# Explicit specialization must precede its first use

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I need to be able to insert stub code into a template function, where the stub code is specialized. This is allowed by most compilers if I use a trampoline like

```cpp
template <class T>
T foo(T t) {
   if(Stub<T>::enabled) {
      return Stub<T>::stub(t);
   }
   /* actual code here */
}

/* use of foo occurs here */

template <>
int Stub<int>::stub(int) { /* stub code */ }
```

At least this works for most versions of GCC, clang and MSVC. There are some older versions of GCC and GCC-derived compilers that do not accept this and complain that explicit specialization of `Stub<T>::stub` cannot occur after its first use.

My question is -- is there a workaround for these compilers -- and if not, is this something that's allowed as far as the standard is concerned? Or am I relying on GCC/Clang/MSVC to all just "do the right thing"?

Comment: "is there a workaround for these compilers" - Why bother? Why not just drop support for obsolete compilers?

Comment: I'm in a business context. We can't just drop support for customers' compilers.

Comment: You could *try*. I get the "business context" argument, but sometimes you also have to push a little to get customers/users to upgrade - or you'll be stuck in C++98 or similar, with obsolete tool chains, for decades. Not beneficial for anyone.

Comment: In many cases, there may be only one compiler for their platform. Dropping support for their compiler usually means dropping the customer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ODR issue. I think no diagnostic is required, but the code is ill formed nonetheless.

To fix this, you can *declare* the specialization before defining it:

```
template <class T>
T foo(T t) {
   if(Stub<T>::enabled) {
      return Stub<T>::stub(t);
   }
   /* actual code here */
}

/* declaration */
template <>
int Stub<int>::stub(int);

/* use of foo occurs here */

template <>
int Stub<int>::stub(int) { /* stub code */ }
```

Why I think it's an ODR issue.

Look at [example1](https://godbolt.org/z/0OO4Qt) and [example2](https://godbolt.org/z/A5ZCv8). Both use the template the same way. One is inlining the primary template and the other is calling the missing specialization, since the specialization might be in another translation unit somewhere.

Adding the specialization to another translation unit in exaxple 1 would be IFNDR, which can be really hard to debug.

Answer (score 3):

In this use of the function foo

> /* use of foo occurs here */

there is implicitly instantiated specialization `Stub<int>::stub(int)`.

However the declaration of the specialization is provided after the instantiation

```
template <>
int Stub<int>::stub(int) { /* stub code */ }
```

The program is ill-formed. However the Standard does not require a compiler diagnostic.

From the C++ 17 Standard (17.8.3 Explicit specialization)

> 6 **If a template, a member template or a member of a class template
>   is explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared
>   before the first use of that specialization that would cause an
>   implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in
>   which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.** If the program
>   does not provide a definition for an explicit specialization and
>   either the specialization is used in a way that would cause an
>   implicit instantiation to take place or the member is a virtual member
>   function, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. An
>   implicit instantiation is never generated for an explicit
>   specialization that is declared but not defined.

What you need is to write the code such a way that it would satisfy the Standard. That is place the declaration of the explicit specialization before the implicit instantiation.